# ValueError: ('Series lengths must match to compare' when Using Pandas Style

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

By using [Pandas Style](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html), I am trying to highlight those cells that have been (row-wised and column-wised) subsetted from the dataframe (as shown below) with a conditional formatting:

[image]

For instance, after subsetting the cells from row 0 and 1 and from column "Adam" and "Gill", I want to highlight those cells green if their values are larger than their corresponding Target value, and orange if less.

However I keep getting the following error when running the code:

`ValueError: ('Series lengths must match to compare', u'occurred at index 0'`)

What can I do to fix this?

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

def AboveTarget(s): # For dataframe style
    green = s > df["Target"]
    orange = s < df["Target"]
    return ["background-color: #86f922" if v else "background-color: #faebde" if w else "background-color: white" for v, w in zip(green, orange)]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Adam": [99.1, 95.2, 83.1],
                   "Gill": [99.2, 96.1, 81],
                   "Louis": [60, 71.5, 99.1],
                   "Target": [99, 98, 95]
                  })

html = (df.style.\
        apply(AboveTarget, subset = pd.IndexSlice[0:1, ["Adam", "Gill"]], axis = 1)
       )

html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `subset` you are passing the sliced elements to the function `AboveTarget`. In combination with `axis=1` the argument `s` to `AboveTarget` will be rows from the DataFrame, i.e., Pandas Series with index `["Adam","Gill"]`. You can't compare that with `df["Target"]`, which is a Series with index `[0,1,2]`.

You need:

```
import pandas as pd

def AboveTarget(s): # For dataframe style
    green = s > s["Target"]
    orange = s < s["Target"]
    return ["background-color: #86f922" if v else "background-color: #faebde"\
        if w else "background-color: white" for v, w in zip(green, orange)]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Adam": [99.1, 95.2, 83.1],
               "Gill": [99.2, 96.1, 81],
               "Louis": [60, 71.5, 99.1],
               "Target": [99, 98, 95]
              })

html = (df.style.\
        apply(AboveTarget, subset = pd.IndexSlice[0:1, ["Adam", "Gill", "Target"]], axis = 1)
       )

html
```

Pass the column "Target" to the function and compare with the corresponding `s["Target"]` value.

Answer (score 1):

In AboveTarget, you are trying to compare a `pd.Series` called `s` - that also happens to have less elements... - with a dataframe `df`, and that's why it doesn't work.

One way is to do the following:

```
def AboveTarget(s, df): # For dataframe style
    green = s > df.loc[s.name, "Target"]
    orange = s < df.loc[s.name, "Target"]
    return ["background-color: #86f922" if v 
            else "background-color: #faebde" if w 
            else "background-color: white" 
            for v, w in zip(green, orange)]

html = (df.style.\
        apply(AboveTarget, subset = pd.IndexSlice[0:1, ["Adam", "Gill", "Louis"]],
              axis=1, args=(df,))
       )

html
```

[image]

I'm passing `df` as an argument.

---

Another way, which I like better because it doesn't require such a complicated IndexSlice and doesn't require passing `df` as an extra argument is as follows:

```
def AboveTarget(s):
    green = s > s['Target']
    orange = s < s['Target']
    return ["background-color: #86f922" if v 
            else "background-color: #faebde" if w 
            else "background-color: white" 
            for v, w in zip(green, orange)]

html = (df.style.\
        apply(AboveTarget, subset = pd.IndexSlice[0:1], axis=1)
       )

html
```

It works because `Target` isn't either `> Target` or `< Target` so it will get a background color of `white`